# Is it possible for a human being to live on a different day cycle?

Tags: physiology, sleep

I am considering writing a story where a character lives on a 30-hour day cycle.

That is, this person sleeps for 9.5 hours and is awake for 20.5 hours.  Then this person repeats the schedule.

I'd like to know from those of you whom are more knowledgeable about biology and physiology whether this is possible.

Comment: Yes, it is certainly possible. Whether or not it's healthy is a different question!

Comment: Any chance this is motivated by https://xkcd.com/320/ ?

Comment: Ha.  Nice find.  I hadn't seen that one.